# PHP - While loop

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

```
print "<ul>";
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    echo("<li>" . $value[storeid] . " " . ($value[dvdstock] + $value[vhsstock]) . "</li>");
}
print "</ul>";
```

Will output

```
•2 20
•2 10
•1 20
•1 20
•1 10
```

I was wondering how I would adapt this loop so it outputs the total values for each &value[storeid]

```
•1 50
•2 30
```

Thanks very much :)

Comment: if these values are coming from the database then you will have to change you sql accordingly so that the resultset contains the total number also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use another array to calculate the values you want:

```
// setup a quick place to store the data
$stores = array();
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    if(!isset($stores[$value['storeid']])){  // init check required to avoid Notices
        $stores[$value['storeid']] = $value['dvdstock'] + $value['vhsstock'];
    }else{
        $stores[$value['storeid']] += $value['dvdstock'] + $value['vhsstock'];
    }
}
ksort($stores);  // sort by storeid ASC

print "<ul>";
// loop through the new data
foreach ($stores as $id => $value) {
    echo("<li>" . $id . " " . ($value) . "</li>");
}
print "</ul>";
```

[Demo Link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8f16e6e1678b4c7fa41afb8d373d36c998dbc06d)

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting the data from an SQL database then you should do this using `SUM()` functions in the SQL as it is more efficient.  If the data source is from somewhere else you should do something like this:

```
//Sum data
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    if (!isset($sums[$value['storeid']])) {  // init check required to avoid Notices
        $sums[$value['storeid']] = $value['dvdstock'] + $value['vhsstock'];
    } else {
        $sums[$value['storeid']] += $value['dvdstock'] + $value['vhsstock'];
    }
}
ksort($sums);  // sort by storeid ASC

print "<ul>";
foreach ($sums as $key => $sum) {
    echo("<li>$key $sum</li>");
}
print "</ul>";
```

[Demo Link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4091c234f6af118c87151d5e0d7db6135a22b2a0)

Comment: If you were summing anyway, why not `SELECT storeid, SUM(dvdstock+vhsstock) as stock FROM TABLE storestock GROUP BY storeid` ?

Comment: @gnarf: Have you read the first sentence?: *If you are getting the data from an SQL database then you should do this using SUM() functions in the SQL as it is more efficient*

Comment: Have you read my comment? I read the first sentence, and then said "Why doesn't he add dvdstock and vhsstock together in the query too?" ;) - Also, I thought having an example SQL query that used `SUM()` might be useful to the OP considering the question.

Comment: @gnarf: I agree with the example. But Chris does say anything about how to sum the values so maybe he had the same in mind as you. But anyway, example is good :)

Answer (score 0):

It is a `for` loop and you have to make two of them. First to compute the sum and then to iterate over these values:

```
$data = array();

foreach ($arr as $value) {
    if (!isset($data[$value['storeid']])) {  // init check required to avoid Notices
        $data[$value['storeid']] = $value['dvdstock'] + $value['vhsstock'];
    } else {
        $data[$value['storeid']] += $value['dvdstock'] + $value['vhsstock'];
    }    
}
ksort($data);  // sort by storeid ASC

print "<ul>";
foreach ($data as $storeid => $sum) {
    echo('<li>' . $storeid . ' ' . ($sum) . '</li>');
}
print "</ul>";
```

[Demo Link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ed7d7b4c9c3c9946e70998aa1953bd445f26e2ca)

Btw one word about strings:
Either use single quotes `'` with concatenation `.`: `'foo: ' . $bar`.
Or double quotes `"` and put the variables inside the string: `"foo: $bar"`.

Answer (score -1):

Correct version:

```
<?php

$initial = array (
    array (
        'id'     => 1,
        'amount' => 10
    ),
    array (
        'id'     => 1,
        'amount' => 10
    ),
    array (
        'id'     => 2,
        'amount' => 20
    ),
    array (
        'id'     => 2,
        'amount' => 20
    ),
    array (
        'id'     => 2,
        'amount' => 20
    ),
);

$result = array ();

foreach ($initial as $value) {
    $result[$value['id']] += $value['amount'];
}

print_r($result);

?>
```

Comment: I doubt this will do anything useful, its basically copying the array from one array to another but using `+=`

Comment: WTF, no, it would go through the initial array, and sums up the total for each unique key.

Comment: I have downvoted this answer because it does not use the OP's sample input data, does not provide the desired output, generates Notices, and is a code-only answer.  If you are able to edit this post to form a unique, valuable answer, I will consider removing my downvote and possibly upvoting it.  Otherwise, please consider removing this post to reduce page bloat.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$sums = array();
foreach ($arr as $value)
{
    $sums[$value['storeid']] += $value['dvdstock'];
}
print_r($sums);
?>
```

Comment: I've downvoted this code-only answer because it does not provide the desired output and it generates Notices.  If you are able to edit this answer to form a unique, valuable method, I will consider removing my downvote and possibly upvoting it.  Otherwise please consider removing this post to reduce page bloat.

Comment: Thanks, @mickmackusa, but I think this answer is fine as it is. I know the code isn't perfect, but I think StackOverflow isn't meant as a canihazthecodes site. The code in my answer shows the concept of a solution. It isn't meant to be copy-pasted in production code.